# on_reaction_add in discord does not seem to work

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    print('reaction added')
```

When I add a reaction it does not seem to print 'reaction added', I've added the reaction after the bot went online but still does not works.
full code:

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
   print('logged on!')

@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
   print('reaction added')

client.run('token_here')
```

Comment: I don't see how this shouldn't work, try providing some more code.

Comment: Ive simplify my code above, it logs on but just does not print it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem comes from because the message was sent **before** your bot started. As written in the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_reaction_add):

> If the message is not found in the internal message cache, then this event will not be called.

**You sould use [`on_raw_reaction_add`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_raw_reaction_add)**, wich works even if the message wasn't in the internal cache (so sent before the bot started). This returns a [payload](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.RawReactionActionEvent) that contains ids instead of objects (so convert them if necessary).

I hope it will solve your problem

Comment: Yea it worked after i removed the 'user' argument. Thanks man!

Comment: But is there a way to get the user id of the user who added the reaction?

Comment: Use the `user_id` propriety of the payload object.